# Я потерял структуру XML, кто поможет ее отыскать?

Tags: php, xml, curl, soap

Отправляю запрос через плагин Mozilla, HttpRequester в ответ приходит как и обещает документация API XML, спарсить который не составляет труда.
[image: Скриншот ответа из программы]

Но в реальном запросе через CURL на PHP в ответ приходит просто строка уже вынутых из структуры значений

Вот код CURL:

```
$xml1 = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:api="https://api.reformagkh.ru/api_document_literal">
  <soapenv:Header>
     <api:Login soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
        <login>ipkrochinde</login>
        <password>reestrdoma</password>
     </api:Login>
  </soapenv:Header>
  <soapenv:Body>
     <api:GetHouseInfo>
        <address>
            <houseguid>'.$id.'</houseguid>
        </address>
     </api:GetHouseInfo>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>';


// HTTP authentication  
$url = "https://api.reformagkh.ru/api_document_literal";  

$ch = curl_init();   
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);   
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, 
       array('Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8', 
             'Content-Length: '.strlen($xml1)));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml1);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if ($result == NULL) {
echo "Error:\n";
echo curl_errno($ch) . " - " . curl_error($ch) . "\n";
} else {
 print_r($result);
}
```

Помогите получить полноценный XML, в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Попробуйте вместо `print_r` использовать `var_dump`

Comment: В таком случае там будет сообщение "string(2032)"

Comment: В общем суть в том, что **на самом деле** все теги на месте, просто `print_r` выводит данные как есть и браузер, что естественно, их скрывает - на то он и браузер. Обрамите вывод таким образом `echo '<pre>';print_r($result);echo '</pre>'`